# How to create a form with fields for all instances of another model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm new to Django and I'm currently trying to create a form which should contain input fields for all existing objects of another model. Let's say that I would like to manage my supplies at home and make sure that I have enough of various products at diffect storage locations.

For example, I would like to make sure that the storage locations `bathroom` and `basement` should always have plenty of the supply `toilet paper`. I don't need `toilet paper` in the location `kitchen`. The storage locations are pre-defined and available through a model. I couldn't find any way to create a form for `Supply` which dynamically generates form fields for `MinimumQuantity` objects based on all available `StorageLocation` objects.

My form should look like this when creating the supply "toilet paper":

```
supply name: <input example: "toilet paper">

minimum supply quantities

    bathroom - amount: <input example: 6>
    kitchen  - amount: <input example: 0>
    basement - amount: <input example: 3>
```

I'm a bit lost here and any hints would be much appreciated.

This is my current code (shortened):

models.py:

```
class Supply(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class StorageLocation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MinimumQuantity(MinimumQuantity):
    storage_location = models.ForeignKey(StorageLocation, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    supply = models.ForeignKey(Supply, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py:

```
class SupplyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Supply
    template_name = "supplies_form.html"
    fields = [ 'name', ]
```

supplies_form.html:

```
<div class="card-body">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
</div>
```

I stumbled upon various related questions on stackoverflow and other sites and fiddled around with formsets, but my issues seem to be that:

1. I have a one-to-many from Supply to MinimumQuantity and can't think of any way to tell Supply about it, and
2. while all StorageLocation objects exist already, the MinimumQuantity objects don't.

Have I perhaps even made this construct too complicated and is there perhaps a way to solve the whole thing without the MinimumQuantity model at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this, we have to use a ModelForm and set the fields attribute to include the fields of the MinimumQuantity model that you want to include in the form. In your case, this would be the storage_location field and the amount field.

Now, First add this in your code and make changes to SupplyCreateView:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class MinimumQuantityForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MinimumQuantity
        fields = ['storage_location', 'amount']

class SupplyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Supply
    template_name = "supplies_form.html"
    form_class = MinimumQuantityForm
    fields = ['name']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['minimum_quantities'] = MinimumQuantity.objects.all()
        return context
```

---

and then in your supplies_form.html do like this:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<div class="card-body">
    <h4>Minimum supply quantities</h4>
    {% for minimum_quantity in minimum_quantities %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id_{{ minimum_quantity.storage_location.name }}">{{ minimum_quantity.storage_location.name }}</label>
            <input type="number" name="{{ minimum_quantity.storage_location.name }}" id="id_{{ minimum_quantity.storage_location.name }}" required>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Thank you! I had to slightly adjust the code because having `form_class` and `fields` in `SupplyCreateView` is not allowed. I removed `fields` and changed `form_class` to `Supply`. In the form I added the `value` property to the number field. 
Unfortunately this solution only shows `MinimumQuantity` form fields for existing objects. In addition, each `Supply` should have its own `MinimumQuantity` objects. Nevertheless I'll take this as an approach to continue from here.

Comment: Cheers, Good luck on your project!